# About Crystal Reports in SQL Server?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-2008

I want to create a Crystal Report for particular engineer installation details. In that report I want to show to no of installation details for particular engineer.

Report model looks like this:

```
totalnoofinstallation  assignto  c_address   c_mobileno  package_det frm_date    to_date
  3                     FE01      Ramnagar    232345      xx         25-04-2012 05-04-2012
```

SQL Server table data look like this:

```
p_id  assignto c_address C _mobileno  package_det  frm_date      to_date
 1      FE01    Ramnagar    232345      xx         25-04-2012    05-04-2012
 2      FE01    kknagar     232345     xx         03-04-2012    04-04-2012
 3      FE01    colony      232345      xx         01-02-2012    23-02-2012
```

My procedure is

```
create procedure sp_fldinstallationdeatils
(
   @assign varchar(20),
   @frmdate1 varchar(20),
   @todate1 varchar(20)
)
as
begin
   select 
      count(*) as tonofoinstallation, Assignto, 
      customer_address, customer_contactno, package_details, frmdate, todate   
   from 
      installation2 
   where 
      assignto='FE01' and frmdate ='25-04-2012' and todate= '05-04-2012' 
   group by 
      Assignto, customer_address, customer_contactno, package_details, frmdate, todate 
end
```

but my report shows only (I want to show total no of installation as 3 in my report)

```
totalnoof installation
 1
```

I don't like to create another procedure to count the total no of installation details. What changes I make in the existing procedure to show the details of totalnoofinstallation? Pls help me?

Comment: Yes you must accept answers if you feel it is correct. This is how people are encouraged to answer questions in this forum. You may not get satisfactory answers in some questions in those case you may not vote or accept an answer. But 0% !!! you need to work on it....

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  count(*) as tonofoinstallation, Assignto, 
  customer_address, customer_contactno, package_details, frmdate, todate   
from 
  installation2 
where 
  assignto='FE01' and frmdate ='25-04-2012' and todate= '05-04-2012'
```

The condition " and frmdate ='25-04-2012' and todate= '05-04-2012' " will cause the sql to return only one row according to the data you had given.